# Interfaces and Getters\Setters

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following:

```
interface IEngine {
    type():string;
    type(type:string):void;
}

class Engine implements IEngine {
    private _type: string;

    get type():string {
        return this._type;
    }

    set type(type:string) {
        this._type = type;
    }


}

var engine = new Engine();
engine.type = 'foo';
```

The interface looks to me to be implemented, however, running tsc throws an exception:

```
F:\>tsc interfaces.ts --target "es5"
interfaces.ts(11,7): error TS2420: Class 'Engine' incorrectly implements interface 'IEngine'.
  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ (): string; (type: string): void; }'.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are implementing property, so in interface it should be like this:

```
interface IEngine {
    type:string;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Interfaces in Typescript are great for defining the "shape" of the object you want. In your example you are looking for an object that has a property called `type`. This can be done by specifying:

```
interface IEngine {
    type: string;
}
```

The getters and setters are *implementation details* which are then defined in objects that implement the interface such the `Engine` type in your question.